# Execute some code if create/update/destroy action is successful without callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Right now I have a model `Trip` that when saved, runs some callbacks. I want to isolate this behavior so that it happens only when it runs on the controller (create/update/destroy), so I want to remove the callbacks.

Assuming I have a service object `DoSomething#call` which accepts `trip` and does everything I need, what are my options to run it in `create/update/destroy`?

I have a few ideas but they involve horror things like:

```
def create
  super() do |success, failure|
    @action_successful = failure.instance_of?(
      InheritedResources::BlankSlate
    ) || failure.class.nil?
    if @action_successful
      DoSomething.call(Trip.find(params[:id]))
    end
  end
end
```

Which comes with a lot of downsides:

- The horrible way to detect if an action is successful
- No way to get the in-memory reference to the object being acted on (reload from db)
- Since I have no reference to the in memory object, it's quite problematic to run something during on destroy (no reference, can't reload)

### Additional code as requested

```
class Trip
end
```

The custom service (I've multiples)

```
class SaveLastChangedTrip
  def call(user, trip)
    return if user.nil?
    user.update_attributes!(last_trip: trip)
  end
end
```

and the activeadmin file

```
ActiveAdmin.register Trip do
  controller do
    def update
      if super() # This is pseudocode, I want to run this branch only if save is successful
        SaveLastChangedTrip.call(current_user, resource)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hello, have you considered using an observer pattern https://medium.com/@mitchocail/observer-pattern-in-ruby-e80ac3c1dac7?

Comment: Hello @Bohdan , the observer pattern would fit, but I have no access to the in-memory copy of the object, not that I'm aware of, so it gets a bit complicated even "watching" the object to use the observer pattern

Comment: could you add more code? Problem looks complicated and more info would be helpful

Comment: Sure, added an example of what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: hey, I'm not familiar with ActiveAdmin but from what I've read you may be able to access object with `@trip = Trip.find(params[:id])`, also you may try to insert `debugger/binding.pry` to see what data you have

Comment: With rails is straightforward, the problem is indeed activeadmin itself, I found that in their public API `resource` is cached, problem is I still have no way to know if the save was successful or not, maybe I can check for `errors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    def create
      create! do |success, failure|
        success.html do
          DoSomething.call(resource)
        end
      end
    end
```

See [comments.rb](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9cffa4a8113405a6fb0a73b9ec725a1d55ed039a/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments.rb#L53) for similar example.

Comment: Yes thanks I ended up with something similar. Athough I really don't like the `success.html`, looks like is the only way.